# How to create GTK3 app with CMake and Eclipse CDT on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, gtk3

I trying create simple gtk3 app for windows. Gtk3 has been installed with official instruction by mysys. I created cmake app in eclipse. I tried create simple gtk3 app and it compiled successful, but Eclipse show errors. And when I run compiled app it failed.

[image]
CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (EITSoftGTK)


FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

# Setup CMake to use GTK+, tell the compiler where to look for headers
# and to the linker where to look for libraries
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Add other flags to the compiler
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(EITSoftGTK EITSoftGTK.cpp)

# Link the target to the GTK+ libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(EITSoftGTK ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is very probable that your application is missing a DLL; use dependency walker to verify that all its dependencies are found. You may need to copy some DLLs to the build directory and/or adjust your (system) %PATH%.

Comment: As for the Eclipse issue: You may need to configure the include path separately for the Eclipse editor.

Comment: Yes I used dependency walker and it showed that i haven't many API-WS-WIN-... and EXT-MS-WIN... DLL. Where can I find it?

Comment: I updated my question with dependency walker output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remarked in my comment, you need to make sure **all** dependencies are accessible. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) describes how DLLs are located, but by far the easiest is to copy the missing DLLs (`libgio...` and `libgobject...`) into the same directory as your executable.

Comment: But libgio and libgobject located in dir with my .exe and added to system path

Comment: Maybe because some libs is x86 ?

Comment: Yes, the architecture should match your executable.